# Can I post app with different name and icon in iTunes and different name and icon in app?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to make one name and icon in iTunes and when I install that app in iPhone then different name and icon appears in my iPhone?

Comment: Apple expects them to generally match. Obviously the larger iTunes image can have a little more detail than the small app icon but they should be the same basic image. Same for the app name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. The name of the app on the iTunes Store can be different from the display name of the app on phone. Same is the case with iTunes Store Image and App icon(show on mobile).
Of course, if you can, doesn't mean you should. :D 
For consistency, I would prefer to have the same name and icon at both places.

Answer (score 0):

Application name and icon is not valid to change.

> No, the icon is specified in the application bundle, which you must
>   not change. If you change it, your app signature will become invalid
>   (not the same checksum) and thus your app won't run anymore.